# Flutter list item is not being removed from UI

Tags: flutter, listview

I checked that item is removed from both my db and object list but it still remains on the UI.

```
showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        child: AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text("Edit task"),
                          content: StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                void Function(void Function()) setState) {
                              return Column(
                                children: [                              
                                  const Text('Delete your task forever '),
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () async {
                                        await 
                                          DatabaseHelper.instance.delete(int.parse(itemID));

                                      
 setState(() => Rung.myList = List.from(Rung.myList)..removeAt(int.parse(itemID)));
                                        
var element = Rung.myList.elementAt(int.parse(itemID));

                                        
dev.log('Removed item exist in current list?: ${Rung.myList.contains(element)}');


                                      },
                                      child: const Icon(
                                          Icons.restore_from_trash_outlined),
                                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `removeAt`, you should pass an index of the item of the list instead of itemID.

Comment: It is the index

Comment: You are using the same value in the list to delete which is used for the database. There should be a different.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and some changes in your code :

```
setState(() => Rung.myList = List.from(Rung.myList)..removeAt(int.parse(itemID)));
```

> To

```
setState(() {
  Rung.myList.removeAt(int.parse(itemID));
});
```